# How to call an external API url with parameter in flask?

Tags: curl, flask, python-requests

I'm a bit struggling while calling an external URL including a parameter from my flask application (route) to external web application.

In a terminal window I call the API using CURL (which is working):

```
curl https://api.mytimestation.com/v1.1/employees/{emp_yj7n80o} -u myapikey:
```

I try to use this in a Flask route to get data from that external URL in order to process it and use it in my own Flask application.

Started using REQUESTS module but can't get it working due to:

- HTTPS error
- data field seems to be faulty

*Tried so far:*

```
import requests

r = requests.post('https://api.mytimestation.com/v1.1/employees/{emp_yj7n80o}', data={'-u myapikey:'})
```

Anyone that can help me with some tips on how to progress? 
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I was already heading to the solution. Had to make some changes in order to make it work.

Sharing the solution, so anyone searching for same problem this post can be helpful.

-   -

To start with I have to: 
1. replace the POST with GET, kind of obvious since I intent to retrieve information. (https wasn't any problem originally)

2. Add BASIC HTTP authentication to the REQUESTS object. And replace the user object with the API key.

Code then looks like:

```
import requests
url = 'https://api.mytimestation.com/v1.1/employees'
x = requests.get(url, auth = ('myAPIkey', '')) 
print(x.text)
```